# dsofile wrong pagecount

Tags: asp-classic, ms-word

I am using dsofile.dll to get pagecount from word documents, all I need at this point is pagecount and only Word documents at this time.

For some documents the pagecount returns as 0 (or invalid in general maybe?) and therefore I'm in need of a solution or a different approach.

Word automation is a last resort as it is considered unsafe and will otherwise overload the server.

Any ideas ?

**CODE:**

```
<%
dim dso : Set dso = Server.createObject("DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties")
dso.open(wordFilePath)
response.write dso.summaryProperties.pageCount
dso.close()
set dso = nothing
%>
```

EDIT1: Still no progress, trying word automation came up with loads of problems which can be seen here: [Server Word automation permissions (some answers and some questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863012/server-word-automation-permissions-some-answers-and-some-questions), answers are most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's going to depend on whether pagination has been performed for the doc before it was saved. If the doc has autopaginate turned off, I don't think the PAGES metadata property get's set (along with several other doc properties), which is, I'm guessing, what that dsofile.dll library is using to retrieve the page count. In short, that's not terribly reliable. About the only way I know to accurately get a page count is load the doc in word, force pagination, and then read the pages property.

Comment: Currently i am using word automation and it works though quite slow.
The puzzeling thing to me is that in windows when you mouse over a word document it tells you how many pages it is even for documents DSO cannot count... so how the hell does windows knows how many files the document is without launching a word process ??? Microsoft is hiding something and its bugging me :)