# Word Automation from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, word-2013

I created a Windows application which starts a Word process (Microsoft.Office.Interopt.Word) with C#. I load two addins word.AddIns.Add(@"C:\temp\addin.dot", true);. This code works perfectly fine within my windows application.

To be able to start this process remotly, I created a MVC web application. The web app uses the same code, but it failes on the part where I load the addins:

**error:** Word cannot open this document template: (C:\temp\addin.dot)

The web application uses an application pool with administrator permissions and following settings:

- Enable 32-Bit Applications: True
- Load User Profile: True

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be? Why does the same code behave differently on the web server?

Edit: The task manager shows me that the word process gets started with the correct user account. It is the same account as I use, when I start the windows application.

Answer (score 5):

Web servers aren't meant to run user applications. Since you're using a COM reference, the library requires the application to be running to perform manipulations.

If you're looking to automate document generation/reading, my advise would be to use a library like DocX. This would enable you to work directly with the file format itself without bringing in COM references (the interop libraries).

Comment: I use it to migrate different things from the normal.dot like autotext, building blocks and so on. In addition I open old templates (word 2003) check if they have macros in it and save it as new templates (*.dotx / *.dotm).

Comment: If it requires a user (which interop does) you're going to need to turn it into a server that runs under a user's context which is then accessible to the web server. But IIS can't launch word.

Comment: I know that IIS isn't meant to run an application like word. I evaluated different libraries like the DocX but since we need specific functionality from word we decided to use the interop. The web app will be used online for migration purpose and will be executed only by one user, but remotely. I do other stuff as well in the migration process and all of it works (like Active Directory manipulations, exection of console applications and so on).

Comment: In fact, such server side Office automation is forbidden officially, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office Workarounds are mentioned, and third party solutions like DocX are usually the right way to go if they do support running on IIS.